# Comma separated search

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch records where interests=IN6330,IN8408. URL is `example.com?interests=IN6330,IN8408.` Tried with below query but only one parameter at a time. Comma separated values can be single or multiple.

```
SELECT * FROM `interests` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('IN8408',interests)
```

[image]

Comment: use 'IN' clause in your query

Comment: This comes up every day try googling mysql search comma separated string.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh. This is why people grumble about normalization. SQL is pessimized (the opposite of optimized) to search for matches in strings of comma separated values.

Best path to success: Normalize your database by creating a new table for `interests` which can have multiple items, each in its own row. In entity-relationship jargon, you need an `interest` entity with a many-to-one relationship to its parent `item`. Then a query of the form

```
 SELECT item.something, item.another, interests.interest
   FROM item
   JOIN interests on item.interest_id = interests.interest_id
  WHERE interests.interest IN ('IN6330','IN8408')
```

will work, and work with great efficiency.

If you **must** keep these comma separated values in your table you will need a much more laborious and verbose approach to doing an `IN`-like search.

Something like this may do it for you.

```
 SELECT * FROM interests WHERE FIND_IN_SET('IN6330',interests)
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM interests WHERE FIND_IN_SET('IN8408',interests)
```

But as you can see it's nasty: nasty enough that the person working on your software after you will curse your name.

Normalize!

Answer (score 0):

maybe the clausule **IN** is that your need.
by example

select * from interest where interests **in** ("IN6330","IN8408")

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) is the reference.

Comment: its only returning "IN6330" values

Answer (score 0):

First, replace comma separated values with **|**

```
$search="IN6330,IN8408";
$result = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', '|', trim($search));
SELECT * FROM `interests` WHERE `interests` REGEXP $result
```